# C++ Developer functions that can only be called by other developer functions

Tags: c++, c++17

We have a number of functions that are very useful for developing and testing, but should not be part of any productive code - mostly for performance reasons. Our goal is to have the compiler ensure that functions marked as `DEV_ONLY` can only be called by functions with the same tag.

How would I implement something like:

```
virtual int foo() DEV_ONLY;

int bar() {
  foo(); // fails
}

int blah() DEV_ONLY {
  foo(); // works
}
```

with DEV_ONLY being a macro or something else?

The following ideas have been proposed so far, but are not completely what I am looking for:

- volatile: One option that I found was to mark them as "volatile" [(see Dr. Dobbs)](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766), but I have two issues with that. First, it would misuse a specifier that has different semantics, potentially causing issues in the future. Second, the compiler warnings about functions being "volatile" would not be as helpful.
- friend: In my understanding, this would require friendship to be declared in the class that implements such a method. Since the tests or dev tools that use the method are not known beforehand, I am not a friend of the friend solution.
- not exporting: The code that may or may not use the method is possibly even within the same class.
- substituting with noop in Release build: Tests might still require those methods in Release mode.

Comment: What about not exporting them?

Comment: You might be able to use `friend`ship for this.

Comment: `#ifdef DEV_ONLY` ? or create a dedicated library: DevOnlyLib ?

Comment: And macro magic to substitute the function names into no-ops under release configurations...

Comment: maybe move the DEV_ONLY inside the parantheses to work as some kind of dummy arguments? not pretty though

Comment: Look, it isn't particularly clear yet what you wish to accomplish. Can you provide a MCVE so we can see what happens in your system?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I edited the question and added some concerns about the approaches.

Comment: *"Tests might still require those methods in Release mode."* The test modules should be separate anyway, so you can locally override the macro magic in them.

Comment: You could put every "dev only" functions into their own namespaces which would forbid you from using them outside without the namespace prefix.

Comment: Holt: This would work with functions, but not with single DEV_ONLY methods of an otherwise public class, would it?

Comment: @mrks No it would not - You could make these method friend non-member functions of these class.

Comment: Please see the issue that I have with "friend" above.

Comment: I had another idea - is there any way to create a custom attribute like this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes
without requiring compiler plugins?

Comment: @mrks The friend solution I propose for member functions does not suffer from the issue you are pointing out since the friendship would work in the other direction. And no it is not possible to create custom attribute in a portable way.

Comment: This is a very hard problem to do cleanly, see [this talk by Scott Meyers](http://nwcpp.org/talks/2007/redcode_-_updated.pdf) using namespace, template metaprogramming and other tricks to get partially there.

Answer (score 2):

The `#ifdef` preprocessor directive should be the most straightforward way to achieve two of your goals:

- not be part of any production code
- ensure that they can only be called from functions with the same "tag" (if they're not there, a build with DEV_ONLY undefined would not compile)

That would mean to wrap the function bodies as well as the corresponding calls.

As to the test methods that should be available in release builds: Then they are not DEV_ONLY, and should not be marked as such.

Comment: I feel like this is the best solution so far. However, I wish there was a way for the compiler to complain right away, not only when I build the project in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to use a build system that allows you to define libraries as test only and restricts production binaries from using them. For example, bazel provides the testonly option (http://bazel.io/docs/be/common-definitions.html#common.testonly)

Then you organize your code into your main binary/library, your test only library, and your test code. That would give you something like:
    cc_library(
      name = "foo",
      srcs = ["foo.cc"],
      hdrs = ["foo.h"],
    )

```
cc_library(
  name = "test-utils",
  srcs = ["test-utils.cc"],
  hdrs = ["test-utils.h"],
  testonly = 1,
)

cc_test(
  ...
  deps = ["foo", "test-utils"],  # works
)

cc_libaray(
  ...
  deps = [..., "test-utils"],  # fails
)

cc_binary(
  ...
  deps = ["test-utils"],  # fails
)
```